# Riddle + cryptogram: Wkkvraazmnjsjdd? Prjlmxnp ulffejy lfxt lsp? Rovn ojs oon jgc!

Tags: riddle, cipher

This is a [cryptogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptogram) puzzle.

You get a riddle-style clue and some encoded text ('ciphertext'). Your task is to find the plaintext (the original, un-encoded, text).

The clue is:

> Conceptualised by Mitsubishi,
>   I Blaise  in a cryptic deepscan of the great strike-slip fault,  
>   For Agnes, but not for Edward Mountain:
>   "Other years in bmx sports - E."

and the ciphertext is:

> Glw Dwgu Rwka Qbrklmv'f Wgfo 
>   fl Ivoqr Zsjyir 
>   svge "Nvbq Ydiwtso lw Wnxmjv" (Gnvusvig, 1973) 
>    
>   Wkkvraazmnjsjdd? 
>   Prjlmxnp ulffejy lfxt lsp? 
>   Yvzsoptgjpustfofy ktd op t k y y opokd. 
>   Vzyopzsnpnfdzijyytzijtetzijylsxt jy jd – 
>   yu keeooeaj kjx ovnax sejtq yjia tq. 
>   Zgdscpgvwo – qshdwhbzgc – xpbzgvwobx-vgxpbhgcwwu? 
>   Whdovna xgs jbo khtkeexzixplysjvykstzp ssc kxpssc! 
>   Rovn ojs oon jgc! 
>   Ovbj yjiasj yspj? 
>   Tsett qop td – 
>   jpz tde, 
>   jpz tde, 
>   jpz tde, 
>   jpc.

The first word of the plaintext is 'The'. The plaintext contains numerous non-dictionary words.

The cipher can be decoded using one of the tools on this page: [Rumkin.com Cipher Tools](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/)

Comment: Might the clue "Other years in bmx sports - E." mean NSSI, which is an acronym for "non-suicidal self-injury"?

Comment: @ChuckHoffmann, great suggestion, but that isn't what I was thinking of.

Comment: Still no accepted answer for this!! Maybe you need to add another hint (or just accept my answer)? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor, but what about the final line? ;)

Comment: @AE Well, what about a hint? :-)

Comment: @randal'thor, you're assuming I can remember it myself. :) All I have now is what's below, "The quotes are intended to mean that the final line should be treated in a different way from the rest of the riddle"

Comment: Well, someone got there in the end :-)

Answer (score 9):

Working from [McMagister's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6134/5373) ...

The answer to the riddle is

> Nessie

Explanation:

*Conceptualised by Mitsubishi,*

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Nessie

*I Blaise in a cryptic deepscan of the great strike-slip fault,*

> "Blaise" could refer to Blaise Pascal, after whom the SI unit of pressure is named. Pressure is high at the bottom of Loch Ness! And Nessie is certainly a "cryptic" beast, part of the field of [cryptozoology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptozoology). [Operation "Deepscan"](http://www.nessie.co.uk/htm/searching_for_nessie/deepscan.html) was a search for Nessie in 1987. Loch Ness was formed by a ["strike-slip fault"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Glen_Fault).

*For Agnes, but not for Edward Mountain:*

> Nessie is a familiar form of the name Agnes. Edward Mountain financed a [search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_Monster#Sir_Edward_Mountain_Expedition_.281934.29) for Nessie in 1934.

*"Other years in bmx sports - E."*

> This is an anagram of *Nessiteras rhombopteryx*, the Latin name proposed for Nessie's species by Peter Scott (itself an anagram of "Monster hoax by Sir Peter S"). See [Rosie F's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40576/5373).

The answer to the riddle should then be used as

> the keyword for a Vigenere cipher,

giving the following plaintext:

> The Loch Ness Monster's Song 
>  by Edwin Morgan 
>  from "From Glasgow to Saturn" (Carcanet, 1973) 
>  
>  Sssnnnwhuffffll? 
>  Hnwhuffl hhnnwfl hnfl hfl? 
>  Gdroblboblhobngbl gbl gl g g g g glbgl. 
>  Drublhaflablhaflubhafgabhaflhafl fl fl – 
>  gm grawwwww grf grawf awfgm graw gm. 
>  Hovoplodok – doplodovok – plovodokot-doplodokosh? 
>  Splgraw fok fok splgrafhatchgabrlgabrl fok splfok! 
>  Zgra kra gka fok! 
>  Grof grawff gahf? 
>  Gombl mbl bl – 
>  blm plm, 
>  blm plm, 
>  blm plm, 
>  blp.

Yes, this really is plaintext, not more ciphertext!

Comment: +1 Pretty good, but still quite a few bits left to get! :) Blaise? cryptic deepscan? more on the 'great strike-slip fault'? Edward Mountain? "Other years in bmx sports - E."?

Comment: Ah, you're getting there! :)

Comment: @AE - I've now explained 'cryptic deepscan' and 'Edward Mountain'. The only Blaise I know is Pascal, but I can't get a connection there.

Comment: Edward Mountain is right, you've got 'deepscan' too, but not  'cryptic'. 'Blaise' is a bit different to the rest of the riddle, it doesn't relate directly to the keyword itself. Good work though! :)

Comment: "Cryptic beast" is ***almost*** there. Very close! ;) Not Blaise Pascal though.

Comment: @AE - Only the BMX line left! My lack of knowledge of sports is going to be my downfall here :-(

Comment: The quotes are intended to mean that the final line should be treated in a different way from the rest of the riddle, BTW.

Comment: Not sure if you ever spotted the answer by @RosieF below, but she's given you the one missing part if you want to go back to this puzzle after all these years and close it off :)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks for the ping! I hadn't seen Rosie's answer, which has just taught me something new and fun :-) Edited.

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm sure you know me well enough by now to know I have a thing about closure...! ;-)

Comment: @Stiv *guiltily checks my list of unaccepted answers*

Answer (score 5):

Incomplete answer (will figure out the riddle later), I attacked the cryptogram directly on the assumption that a certain cipher was used, and I was correct.

The cipher used is:

> Vigenere cipher with key "mvhhrv"

Plaintext:

> The Loch Ness Monster's Song
> by Edwin Morgan
> from "From Glasgow to Saturn" (Carcanet, 1973)
>
> Sssnnnwhuffffll?
> Hnwhuffl hhnnwfl hnfl hfl?
> Gdroblboblhobngbl gbl gl g g g g glbgl.
> Drublhaflablhaflubhafgabhaflhafl fl fl –
> gm grawwwww grf grawf awfgm graw gm.
> Hovoplodok – doplodovok – plovodokot-doplodokosh?
> Splgraw fok fok splgrafhatchgabrlgabrl fok splfok!
> Zgra kra gka fok!
> Grof grawff gahf?
> Gombl mbl bl –
> blm plm,
> blm plm,
> blm plm,
> blp.

Comment: +1 Interesting. Plaintext is correct of course, and cipher is correct, but that key is not the one I used. Key I used was the answer to the riddle. Are there alternative ways of doing that particular cipher whereby the key would be different? I'm using the encoder/decoder [here (spoiler)](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/vigenere.php), what method are you using?

Comment: I used the tool [here](http://sharkysoft.com/vigenere/).  Your site doesn't seem to specify the method used, but most likely it sets A=0 and Z=25 while my tool uses A=1 and Z=26.

Comment: @McMagister - It looks to me as though you just tried to encrypt instead of decrypt (M=-N, V=-E, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, looks that way.

Answer (score 3):

Dredging this puzzle up from the murky depths: "Other years in bmx sports - E." is

> an anagram of *Nessiteras rhombopteryx*.
>
>  In 1975 the naturalist Sir Peter Scott proposed that as the zoological taxonymic name for the Loch Ness monster. That name can be translated as Nessie, the monster with the diamond-shaped tail. Of course he hadn't seen any such creature -- all he had to go on were photos which purported to show parts of a creature. Scott's proposed name prompted Scottish politician Nicholas Fairbairn to *anagram* that name into "Monster hoax by Sir Peter S.". I see that A E is entering into the same spirit by transforming the name using the same technique.
>
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_Monster#Robert_Rines_studies_.281972.2C_1975.2C_2001.2C_2008.29